# how to deploy java application developed in netbeans to bluemix

Tags: netbeans, ibm-cloud

I have developed Java application using struts 2 framework in netbeans IDE. I want to run this application in bluemix environment with out using the Clound foundry command line interface(CLI). Is there any plugin available for netbeans to reflect the changes in bluemix whenever I do changes in the code?
please advise.

Comment: I normally just upload things in netbeans via ftp. https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/remote-hosting-and-ftp-account.html

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.  Unfortunately your question does not meet the stackover criteria for questions and is likely to get closed.  See here for more information: http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have created a war file.  If so, you can push it as a liberty application using the cloud foundry command line tools:

```
$ cf push <yourappname> -p myapp.war
```

For more information see:

- https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/cloud/library/cl-bluemix-fundamentals-create-and-deploy-a-java-app-to-the-cloud/
- https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/runtimes/liberty/optionsForPushing.html
- https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/starters/install_cli.html

---

**Update:**

I think you can automate the process with Bluemix dev ops services: http://hub.jazz.net/docs/deploy so that every time you commit to a repository such as git a process will be kicked off to build and then deploy to Bluemix. However, I believe a war will still need to be created. You will probably do this via a dev ops services build script that executes your project's build tool which will be ant unless you have choosen to use maven or gradle. After building, your deploy script will call the `cf push ...` command to deploy the war that was just built.

If you have any questions on this process, you should probably raise that as a separate question on stackover

Comment: Hi Chris, Thanks for your response. Just want to understand more. Is there anyway to link my netbeans repository to bluemix. So that, whenever I will do any changes in my code, it will automatically reflects in bluemix without pushing the war explicitly. Please advise

Comment: I have updated the answer to indicate a possible flow using dev ops tools for Bluemix.  Note that the process will probably be triggered by a code commit.  If you want every change locallly to automatically reflect on Bluemix, personally I don't think that is a very good idea because you will be waiting a long time to see each change reflected on Bluemix.  I prefer to run my code locally on my laptop and when I am happy with the changes locally I will then use `cf push` to deploy to Bluemix.

Answer (score 0):

If you're building using maven, you can use the cloudfoundry maven plugin to deploy the application using a maven goal.

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.cloudfoundry</groupId>
        <artifactId>cf-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

You can then deploy using `mvn package cf:push`
Additional configuration is required. See [CloudFoundry Build Tool Integration](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/java/build-tool-int.html)

Comment: Hi Ram, Is there any plugin for netbeans IDE as well. Actually, as per my project requirement, I need to use the netbeans  IDE. Please advise